# Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I need some help with my problem; it seems like Chrome doesn't like to run this code, but on Firefox it works:

```
function createContext(width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "1";
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    return canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Comment: it's works well in my chrome console,try run your code after DOM ready

Comment: possible for duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670530/javascript-error-cannot-call-method-appendchild-of-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086159/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-appendchild-of-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946428/how-to-fix-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-appendchild-of-null http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677879/cannot-call-method-appendchild-to-null-error-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wait for `document.body` to actually exist before calling your function.

The simplest way is to invoke this code at the end of your HTML markup, rather than in the `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

You should also call the `createContext()` function. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gXm8L/

Comment: by definition, the error he's seeing doesn't occur until the function is actually called.

Comment: yes, in the fiddle i just provided, js was set to onDomready, so the element was found and worked. Did i say something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this -

```
window.onload=function(){
    createContext(100, 200);
};

function createContext(width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "1";
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    return canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/j4c7U/82/